# Assigning multiple variables in one select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Price) AS R,
    A.Price
FROM 
    TableA A
INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TableC C ON C.Code = A.Code
WHERE
    C.Type = 125
    AND A.Desc = 10000038
    AND C.YearID = 10000021
GROUP BY 
    A.Price
```

This query returns

| R | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 165 |
| 2 | 487 |
| 3 | 1807 |

Is it possible assigning variables @a = 165, @b = 487, and @c = 1807 in one select?

I wrote this query:

```
WITH P AS (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Price) AS R,
    A.Price
FROM 
    TableA A
INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN 
    TableC C ON C.Code = A.Code
WHERE
    C.Type = 125
    AND A.Desc = 10000038
    AND C.YearID = 10000021
GROUP BY 
    A.Price
)
SELECT
    @a = (CASE WHEN [R] = 1 THEN P.[Price] END),
    @b = (CASE WHEN [R] = 2 THEN P.[Price] END),
    @c = (CASE WHEN [R] = 3 THEN P.[Price] END)
FROM P;
```

But only `@c` gets the value.

Comment: are the variables dynamically generating ?

Comment: @AmalPs, No, declare at the first of query.

Comment: can't try cursor and save the values in each iteration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate. Your query, as it stands, returns 3 rows, which means that the variables are assigned values *3 times* as well. What order this is in is arbitrary too, but it might be that `@a` is first assigned the value `165`, then `NULL`, and then `NULL` again.

If you aggregate, you can return *one* row and then the assignments will work as you expect; with each variable being assigned 1 value (not 3):

```sql
SELECT @a = MAX(CASE WHEN [R] = 1 THEN P.[Price] END),
       @b = MAX(CASE WHEN [R] = 2 THEN P.[Price] END),
       @c = MAX(CASE WHEN [R] = 3 THEN P.[Price] END)
FROM P;
```